# How to deduce using rules of inference

Tags: discrete-mathematics, first-order-logic

I'm very confused on how to use the rules of inference to tackle this problem. Could I get someone guidance to help me solve this? Thanks in advance.

> Given:
>
> - $p \implies q$
> - $\neg p \implies r$
> - $r \implies s$
>
> Prove that $\neg q \implies s$.

Comment: $p \Rightarrow q$ is equivalent to $\neg q \Rightarrow \neg p$.

Comment: A straightforward method is to create a truth table. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @X Yea i know how to make a truth table. What would I be looking for to prove it using one?

Comment: Start with $\lnot q$, then from $p \to q$ get $\lnot p$, then from $\lnot p \to r$ get $r$, then from $r \to s$ get $s$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mathematical logic, we have the concept of a 'contrapositive': the contrapositive of the statement $a \implies b$ is $\neg b \implies \neg a$, and the two are equivalent. To intuitively understand why, replace $a$ with 'this is a tree' and $b$ with 'this contains wood'. To rigorously prove this can be a good exercise in basic logic.

Then, from the givens, we have $\neg q \implies \neg p$. We also have $\neg p \implies r$ and $r \implies s$, so using this chain of transitive inferences, we get $\neg q \implies s$ as wanted.

Comment: Wow that makes sense. It's just hard for me to see where to start. I never thought I could use the contrapositive and then transitivity to get the the end. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can not get help unless you say what rules of inference you are permitting .there are many deductive systems .

Comment: I guess i'm working with valid argument forms. The rules i'm working with are Modus Ponens, Modus Tollens, Generalization, Specialization, Conjunction, Elimination, Transitivity, Proof by Division into cases, and Contradiction rule.

Comment: @JimmyNeutron How exactly is your Proof by Division into cases rule defined?

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the argument by just looking at the given statements. You need to prove $\neg q \implies s$. So suppose $\neg q$ is true. We need to prove $s$ is true. Identify where in the given three propositions can we find $\neg q$ is true. We can take the contrapositive of the first proposition.

Observe from the first proposition $p \implies q$ that we have $\neg q \implies \neg p$. By hypothesis $\neg q$ is true, and so by the first proposition $\neg p$ is true. Using the second proposition, we get that $r$ is true, and from the third proposition, this implies $s$ is also true. Hence, if $\neg q$ is true, then $s$ is true, as was to be shown.

The rules of inference we used are contraposition (which says $a \implies b$ is equivalent to $\neg b \implies \neg a$) and hypothetical syllogism (which says: if $a \implies b$ and $b \implies c$, then $a \implies c$).